# Given an odd integer, $a$ does $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$ has infinitely many prime $p$ solutions?

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

Given an odd integer, $a$ does   $\gcd(a,p-1)=1$ has infinitely many prime $p$ solutions?

One can argue that there are infinitely many numbers $x$ satisfies $\gcd(a,$x$)=1$. How to argue that there are infinitely many prime $p=x+1$.

Any hint?

Comment: When $a=2$ this asks: are there infinitely many even primes?

Comment: If $a$ is even, no...  But if $a$ is odd, my hint would be to apply the Dirichlet arithmetic progression theorem.

Comment: let me correct to odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Dirichlet's theorem, there are infinitely many primes in the arithmetic series $2+na$, ($n\in \mathbb{N}$). 
If $p=2+na$ is such a prime, then $\gcd(a, p-1) = \gcd(a, 1+na) = 1$.